# Facial motion capture - animate armatures

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, motion-capture

I've been doing a little motion capture of my face using the technique outlined in this tutorial https://youtube.com/watch?v=uNK8S19OSmA

It's worked pretty well and the mesh of the face is moving in the viewport as expected.

But when I try to render out a video of this movement the face does not animate and I'm left with footage of an unmoving face.

Am I missing something basic in my understanding of how these armatures are animated?  Do I need to keyframe them individually?  How should I go about this?

Thanks!